# Is there a nice way to copy columns of text from a file using regex into my pasteboard?

Tags: regex, awk, ack, pbcopy

Currently, the solution that I have is kind of ugly and is pretty spaghetti-code like... is there a nice way to do this with a "standard" tool like `ack`?

What I have right now is a file that is in this format:

**crap.txt:**

```
IdentifierA Some Text
IdentifierB Some Other
```

This is how I currently get it:

```
cat crap.txt |
ack (?<=IdentifierA ).+ |
awk '{ print $(NF-1), $NF }' |
pbcopy
```

This will yield `Some Text` in your pasteboard.

Instead of just having `ack` echo out the line that matches the regex and then getting the last two columns of that line with `awk`, can I just get the specific regex match to print out to console? I tried using `grep -o` but that doesn't seem to have positive lookbehind...

Comment: What is the expected output and how to get it? My system does not have `ack` nor `pbcopy` so do not know what this script does.

Comment: You will get `Some Text` in your pasteboard in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some like this:

```
awk '/IdentifierA/ { print $(NF-1),$NF}' crap.txt
Some Text
```

This search for `IdentifierA` and print the two last filed from that line.

Comment: We are here to help, and you did try to solve it.  If you like my answer, accept it by selecting the check mark on the side of the post :)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'IdentifierA\\s*' '$0=$2' file
```

this line would pick all text after your `IdentifierA` (with leading spaces/tabs removed) no matter how many spaces do you have in the target part. that means, you don't have to `print $(NF-n), $(NF-n-1)...` or if the text has `TAB` instead of `space`

E.g  in this case:

```
IdentifierA a b c d e f g h i j k l
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "IdentifierA Some Text
IdentifierB Some Other"|awk -F'IdentifierA\\s*' '$0=$2' 
Some Text

kent$  echo "IdentifierA a b c d e f g h i j k l"|awk -F'IdentifierA\\s*' '$0=$2'
a b c d e f g h i j k l
```

btw, **grep** is a very handy tool if you want to extract text:

```
kent$  echo "IdentifierA a b c d e f g h i j k l"|grep -oP 'IdentifierA\s*\K.*'  
a b c d e f g h i j k l
```